# Nested LINQ IQueryable and WCF WebApi

Tags: wcf, linq, wcf-web-api

I have a method like this that works as expected.

```cs
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<BuildJobModel> GetCustomers()
{
    var context = new MyDataContext(); // ADO.NET Entity Data Model
    var query = from c in context.Customers
                select new CustomerModel {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    Name = c.Name
                };
    return query;
}
```

But when I try to create a more complex query like this, it doesn't work.

```cs
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<BuildJobModel> GetCustomers()
{
    var context = new MyDataContext(); // ADO.NET Entity Data Model
    var query = from c in context.Customers
                select new CustomerModel {
                    CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    Orders = from o in c.Orders
                             select new OrderModel {
                                 OrderId = o.OrderId,
                                 Details = o.Details
                             }
                };
    return query;
}
```

The Models look like this:

```cs
public class CustomerModel
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OrderModel> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class OrderModel
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

The Exception:

Cannot serialize member Proj.CustomerModel.Logs of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Proj.OrderModel, Proj, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface.

**My Goals:**

- I want to be able to expose an IQueryable interface.
- I want to return nested data.
- I want to use my own Models, not the ado.net entities
- I want to hit the database with as few queries as possible (one would be best).

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend **not** exposing `IQueryable` as a return type of a WCF service.

- WCF was designed to return data not queries
- You lose control over the nature of the query: someone might potentially use this query in a way that is resource-intensive

Ideally, if you want to return collections use array or a generic list.

With respect to your list of goals:

1. Can you explain this? I don't see what `IQueryable` interface has to do with nested data.
2. You can still return arrays or lists of *your* models
3. You have better control over performance if you execute query locally and return results instead

**Update:** Have a look at [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx) - that might be able to do what you want.

Comment: that issue was brough up, though the web service is used internally and exclusively by one project so we went that route.

Comment: Returning list of results (instead of IQueryable) does not prevent you from having nested data. All you do is pre-populate any nested data you want to return.

Comment: IQueryable isn't messed with in WCF. It's not like normal c# code

Comment: IQueryable in WCF Web API (!= classic WCF) is used for OData like querying.

Comment: I want to use IQueryable so SQL query will be generated based off the request.  I also want to return nested data, because that is the dataset I need.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're trying to return JSON: the build in JsonFormatter is not able to (de)serialize interfaces. You should try the JSON.NET Formatter from [WebApiContrib](http://webapicontrib.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use an array rather than IEnumerable, like so...

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OrderModel[] Orders { get; set; }
}

public class OrderModel
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

If you're serializing this to json/xml I suspect the built-in serializers don't know what to do with IEnumerable.

Comment: You have to use IEnumerable with LINQ to Entities.  You can't use an Array.